# Vertical animation on menu

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I'm making a dropdown menu and it's working perfectly with the slideUp/slideDown functions from the jquery api. However - if i want a vertical animation instead i can't find any functions in the api to do that. Can anyone enlighten me :)? Is it possible?

Html

```
<ul>

                <li><a href="">Hvem</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hvad</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li class="first-item"><a href="">Produkter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Leveringer</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="">Hvordan</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li class="first-item"><a href="">Reklame</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">PR</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Illustrationer</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="last-item"><a href="">S??dan!</a></li>

            </ul>
```

Jquery

```
<!-- Menu animation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=Groject.ImageSwitch.yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu > ul > li:not(.inpath) ul').hide();
    $('#menu .inpath ul').show();
    $('#menu > ul > li:not(.inpath)').hover(
    function() {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(300);
        $('#menu li.inpath ul').slideUp(300);
    }, function() {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(300);
        $('#menu li.inpath ul').slideDown(300);
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: do you mean horizontal animation? slideUp / slideDown /slideToggle is a vertical animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe a .slideToggle() function

```
$('#menu li.inpath ul').slideToggle(300);
```

It is a kind of "vertical slide"  [Jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

If you mean "horizontal" slide because slide up and slide down are vertical animation you can do

```
 $('.stuff').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
 $('.stuff').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
```

with many parameters this is [Jquery link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide and show documentation

Comment: I've added the jquery UI library... Works like a charm :-)!

Answer (score 0):

See this very handy article from Karl Swedberg for modifying the slide animations

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

It covers sliding animations in both x and y directions. Should be everything you need to know.